# Keras CNN early stopping not working as expected with patience parameter in imbalanced datasets

Tags: keras, cnn, early-stopping

So I want to stop the cnn when a custom (not implemented in keras) logged metric is not improving with a patience of 5 (I chose macro f1 score) and here's what I did:

Created a callback to log the macro f1 score on epoch end and an early stopping:

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_macro_f1', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
macro_f1_callback = MacroF1Callback(x_valid_combined_tfidf, y_valid)
```

And here is the (simplified) output of the fitting:

```
Epoch 1/20
Validation Macro F1 Score: 0.3983

Epoch 2/20
Validation Macro F1 Score: 0.3369

Epoch 3/20
Validation Macro F1 Score: 0.4057

Epoch 4/20
Validation Macro F1 Score: 0.3947

Epoch 5/20
Validation Macro F1 Score: 0.3761

Epoch 6/20
Validation Macro F1 Score: 0.3918

Epoch 7/20
Validation Macro F1 Score: 0.4147  <keras.src.callbacks.History at 0x4cae76210>
```

And after predicting again on the validation data, it seems that the early stopping chose the better weights to be from...epoch 2...

```
F1 score: 0.33687923314086654
```

All this doesn't make sense, because ok, epoch 2 started decreasing the metric since its lower then epoch 1, and it ends in epoch 7, but epoch 7 has a metric even better the epoch 1

Can anyone help me with this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Also please tell me if you want to paste some more code here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my view, all happened as it was supposed to.  EarlyStopping in the 7th epoch concluded: "The lowest metric was seen 5 epochs ago and the model stopped improving, so let's stop the training" - exactly how you defined it.

Your problem is that you want to decrease and not increase your custom metric. However, if your goal is to increase some function, it's not a *loss* function. If I understood it correctly, **you can try putting a minus before the F1 score** to let the model decrease its negative equivalent or give a try to other similar loss functions like [categorical cross-entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy).

Comment: Thanks! I realized what I was doing wrong, I figured the mode='auto' from early stopping would be better, but now that I specified which way the metric should go, it works fine. Tysm for pointing me in the right direction :)